Can Mendeley Reference Manager automatically generate citation keys for bibliographic entries?
I have been using Mendeley Desktop for a while and was recently trying to work with Mendeley reference manager--the new software. However I find that Mendeley reference manager does not automatically generate citation keys for bibliographic entries. That is a big issue, otherwise I would need to write those all myself.
Does anyone know if there is a way to get Mendeley reference manager to generate bibtex citation keys?
Sorry for posting at the borderline between a Latex question and a software specific question. However, Mendeley itself does not have a forum, and it seems that many users on this site are interested in Mendeley--since there is a Mendeley specific tag for posts. Hence I posted here.

Just out of idle curiosity: Why is it a big issue to you to have to write the citation keys for the bibliographic entries?

No idea of the new Mendeley or the older,  but when you have files .bib in a bibtex format you can also other free tools as JabRef or Kbibtex that can do that in seconds.

@Mico I have like thousands of articles in my Mendeley repo, so I want to avoid writing a large number of citation keys manually.

@Fran Oh that is interesting. I have not used Kbibtex lately. My question is about workflow. So as I add new files to my Mendeley bib file, I imagine I will need to re-export the bib file, import into Kbibtex and generate the keys. So would the keys change from import to import? I don't want to use one set of keys and then have those keys change later--which would mess up compiling my articles.

@krishnab The keys are not generated randomly, but fully predictables according to the reference. For instance taking the first surname in lowercase and without tildes + year (e.g., smith1981).  A guess that the only problem could br add another reference with the same surname and year. In that case,  at least Jabref will make also automatically the disambiguation (e.g.,  smith1981a and smith1981b).

@Fran thanks for the solution. Yeah, this is good. I can use this for now. I appreciate the help.

For the old reference manager (Mendeley Desktop), select the desired entries, and press ctrl + K to automatically generate a citation key formatted as lastnameYear.
For the new version of the reference manager, I arrived at this post in search for an equivalent solution.

Haha. Yeah, I ended up importing my library into Zotero, and then getting the citation keys there. It works, but I was hoping to do this all within Mendeley.
